# Execute function one time into "enterFrame"

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to make an one function execute for one time into the loop Game,

```
function loopGame(event)
       if c1 == true then
             ---Execute one function
               comp()
        end
end
```

The problem is that i put this loopGame into the Runtime with "enterFrame", and the loopGame is exec for frame, then comp is execute more than 100 times.

I want a only execute comp a one time.

Thanks

Comment: If this is a multi-threaded environment, you probably need some synchronization blocks.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an upvalue or a global value to keep indicator if the function has already been called:

```
local executed = false -- this will be an upvalue for loopGame function
function loopGame(event)
       if c1 == true and not executed then
             ---Execute one function
             comp()
             executed = true -- set the indicator
        end
end
```

Another option is to use the function itself as the indicator; if it's not used anywhere else (for example, it only does some initialization once), then you can set the function to `nil` after it's done (and save some memory):

```
function loopGame(event)
       if c1 == true and comp then
             ---Execute one function
             comp()
             comp = nil
        end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need it to run once, don't use "enter frame" try this:

```
function loopGame(event)
   if c1 == true then
         ---Execute one function
           comp()
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "goToLoopGame", loopGame )
```

And place the dispatch wherever you want it to start the loopGame function:

```
Runtime:dispatchEvent({ name = "goToLoopGame" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make the flag `c1=false` after calling the `comp()` method, as:

```
function loopGame(event)
    if c1 == true then
      --Execute one function
        comp()
        c1 = false     -- Just add this line and try
     end
end
```

Keep Coding.................. :)

Answer (score 2):

What about having two functions, one that calls comp, and the other which doesn't:

```
function loopGameAfter(event)
       ... other stuff ...
end

function loopGameOnce(event)
       comp()
       ... other stuff ...
       Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", loopGameOnce)
       Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", loopGameAfter)
end
```